# Update sqlite table attribute based on parameter / user selection

Tags: java, sqlite, sql-update

I have an sqlite database with table `salesman` with the following attribute:

```
----------------------
|code|name|isSelected|
----------------------
```

By default, each entry will have `0`under the `isSelected` attribute. Logic is that User selects a Salesman by name in a JCombobox. Upon selection, the `0` in the selected Salesman under the `isSelected` attribute should be `1`.

So example, given data entry of `Salesman`:

```
----------------------
|code|name|isSelected|
----------------------
|0001|John|0         |
----------------------
```

Then User selects `John`, so supposedly, the `0` should be updated to `1`.

Here's my code in updating:

```
public void updateSalesman(String selection){  
    String updateQuery = "UPDATE SALESMAN SET isSelected = '1' WHERE name = 'selection'"; //problem here
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try{
        connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
        ps.executeUpdate();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }        
}
```

I have the update query for making `0` to `1`, but I dont know how to indicate in the method to only update 1 Salesman, based on the user's selection.

EDIT: Changed working code to this:

```
public void updateSalesman(String selection){         
    String updateQuery = "UPDATE salesman SET isSelected = ? WHERE name = ? AND isSelected = ?";
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try{
        connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);

        ps.setInt(1, 1);
        ps.setString(2, "selection");
        ps.setInt(3, 0);
        ps.executeUpdate();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {

        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (connection!= null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Originally, I used this line of code to test generally if update is working:

```
"UPDATE salesman SET isSelected = 1 WHERE isSelected = 0";
```

And, using DB Browser for SQLite, to check on updates in the DB, I saw that all `0` entries were updated to `1` which shows that the code was working but not how I wanted it to be (which is based on 1 selected Salesman). But after applying the  new code (updated, seen above), no changes were made in the database. Any help? Using the updated code, NetBeans console had no problems and everything was going smoothly, except the actual update

EDIT: this line solves it all (thanks to comment below) :

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE SALESMAN SET isSelected = '1' WHERE name = '" + selection + "'";
```

Comment: You are applying the argument incorrectly:  String updateQuery = "UPDATE SALESMAN SET isSelected = '1' WHERE name = '" + selection + "'";  You can't apply the variable named selection as a literal string.

Comment: @DevilsHnd brooo your line solved it all, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

### Use following code:

```
String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE SALESMAN SET isSelected = ? WHERE name = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "selection");
// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

### Resource Link:

[JDBC PreparedStatement example – Update a record](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-update-a-record/)

Comment: applied the code above, but no updates were made to the database :(